# Mount HFS+ filesystem with disable read and write caches

Tags: filesystem, mount, dmg, hfs+

I've got the HFS+ filesystem represented by `.dmg` image file. For security reasons I'd like to make sure every I/O applies directly to the `.dmg` file and not through any kind of memory in the middle.

Is there any way to cancel the option for read and write caching while mounting the filesystem?

During my research (source:  [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html)) about this I discovered that HFS+ hears contain `attributes` field, which refer to volume attributes. One of its containing bits is named `kHFSVolumeNoCacheRequiredBit` and this bit is set if the blocks from this volume should not be cached, which is pretty much what I need.

Any idea how to configure this volume properly (command-line, application, API, etc .. )?

Comment: Where did you read that info?

Comment: @allan, in HFS+ spec here https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html. It's a little out-dated doc, but I guess the filesystem spec haven't changed

Comment: From this in the document you linked:  *This bit is set if the blocks from this volume should not be cached. For example, a RAM or ROM disk is actually stored in memory, so using additional memory to cache the volume's contents would be wasteful.*  Since I can't find a way to set that attribute during the creation of a RAM disk, I'm assuming it's automatic.  If that's the case, then the solution is to create a RAM disk and copy the contents to it bypassing the cache.

Comment: Thanks, i also depicted this information from the spec. I hope there's also a way to use .dmg filesystem with this configuration.